# Civicrm stuck when renewing membership

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I'm running CiviCRM 5.11.0 in Wordpress 5.1.1.
Currently, I'm not able to renew any membership in CiviCRM: Membership section of the selected profile > Renew membership. When I confirm renewal, the system gets stuck in saving screen forever and nothing is registered on the database.

I tested the renewal using a profile page in the frontend, for myself, and it worked. It's only in the backoffice (where I register 99% of membership renewals) where this happens.
Contributions are working fine, it's not an issue of recording payment or the associated contribution.

Do you know what may be causing this issue and how to solve it?

Cheers
João

Comment: In order to rule out the obvious, have you cleared the CiviCRM caches and temp files? Has it been doing this since upgrading to 5.11.0?

Comment: Hi Christia
Yes, all cleared. I upgraded yesterday to 5.11.0 but the behavior was already there before the upgrade, so it's not related to that.

Comment: when you renew via backend does it use a pop up screen and if so, have you tried right-clicking and opening in a new tab? Sometimes doing so will show the error msg which you won't see via the pop up

Comment: Yes, it pops up the renewal screen. I just opened it in a new tab and when I click on save I see the default not found error for my domain (no civicrm related stuff).

Comment: So I'm able to create a new membership in the backend, it's only when changing an existing membership that this occurs (ammend a date, renew, etc)

Comment: DOes anyone knows what to do at least to understand what might be happening?
This happens to any type of edition made to the membership, not only renewal. If I try to edit a current membership (let's say change the end date), it gets stuck forever.

Comment: Which CMS are you using? Which extensions? Have you checked the CiviCRM error logs (under .../civicrm/ConfigAndLog (or, if you use Drupal, the "watchdog")? Are you using price sets (these make problems sometimes)? What's the output of menu> Administration > System Status ?

Comment: Hello
I'm using Wordpress with price sets. system status shows a very long message related with timestamp, starting with "This MySQL database stores certain fields with data-type "DATETIME". To improve timezone support, you may want to change these from "DATETIME" to "TIMESTAMP"."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reminds me of a similar issue I had at a client last week: we received a 403 error when we tried to edit memberships.

The error was due to an anti sql-injection mechanism that was in place at the hosting provider. It could be turned off via the control panel.

Can you check if something similar is active in your installation? Either in the control panel or via a Wordpress security plugin? Ultimately, ask the hosting provider.

Comment: Hi Alain. I will ask the hosting provider, thanks.

Comment: This solved the issue, my provider shut down an injection and is now working. Thanks to you all.